# Prevent strategy cascading in warden authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, warden

I am using devise for authenticating my users for android app **"over an API"**. I have two strategies one for authenticating through password and other for authenticating through otp(for which I use [`active_model_otp`](https://github.com/heapsource/active_model_otp) gem. My problem is I do not want to cascade these strategies. For instance, if my otp stategy is valid and fails authentication it should not try to authenticate through password and return invalid otp message and vice-versa for otp.
Here is my devise initializer file:

```
    config.warden do |manager|
     manager.intercept_401 = false
     manager.strategies.add(:password, Devise::Strategies::Password)
     manager.strategies.add(:otp, Devise::Strategies::Otp)
     manager.default_strategies(scope: :user).unshift :password, :otp
   end
```

Also I recive params like this for password strategy:

```
http://myserver/sessions.json?user[email]=myuser@mail.com&user[password]=12345678
```

And like this for otp strategy:

```
http://myserver/sessions.json?user[email]=myuser@mail.com&user[otp]=12345678
```

Also I am not able to figure out where does this `fail!("Message")` method returns the string "Message" so that I could show it in my android app.

Answer (score 0):

> The Warden::Strategies.add method is a simple way to provide custom strategies. You must declare an @authenticate!@ method. You may provide a @valid?@ method. The valid method should return true or false depending on if the strategy is a valid one for the request.

this is from the documentation of warden strategie: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/hassox/warden/Warden/Strategies/Base

so if you want to have them work exclusively, you could inherit and adapt to the parameter names passed to your application.